# How can I get a consistent timestamp in node.js and/or MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, timestamp, mongoose

I have a node server, and I'm fairly certain that my hosting server is running it across two different machines with slightly different times. So if I make a call to the server that just returns Date.now(), I could see something like this:

```
console.log(firstTime); // 5:30:24
console.log(secondTime); // 5:29:11
```

Even though I retrieved firstTime before I retrieved secondTime.

So I can't trust my server's system time. I also can't use MongoDB's timestamps because they're only precise to the second and I need something with millisecond precision.

I had a thought to store a single record in its own collection, and that record has an integer that I'd increment whenever there's an update, and then I'd store that in the object that was updated, so I'd know which objects were out of date. I'm not sure this is the best way to go, though, and not really sure how to accomplish it using MongoDB/Mongoose, without causing all sorts of subtle timing issues.

What's the best way to go about doing something like this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve and why you need the ms precise timestamps. Are you trying to version your data records for the purpose syncing them between servers?

Comment: Updates can come in faster than once per second. If that happens, two updates can be tagged with the same timestamp (because there's not enough granularity to tell the times apart). There are also processes watching for these updates by polling the timestamp. So update A comes in and a watcher picks it up, and milliseconds later update B comes in and is tagged with the same timestamp (because we haven't moved on to a new second yet) as the previous update, so the watcher never sees update B because it's timestamp is the same as the previous update that it just saw.

Comment: A bit like a message queue then? For what it's worth, I use couchdb which has a changes feed that you could have used.
Is it not possible to add a flag to each item you processed? That way you won't miss anything when the system crashes.

Comment: There are multiple watchers, so I can't flag a thing as "dirty" or "updated", because I don't know who hasn't seen the update yet.

Comment: Each node server could register itself with mongodb at startup and each event generated on it would contain the source server id + the node generated timestamp. That way you could perform a query for each server to get all events which haven't been processed yet.